# How to properly escape a string for use in regular expression in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string, escaping

I am trying to escape a string for use in a regular expression in PHP. So far I tried:

```
preg_quote(addslashes($string));
```

I thought I need `addslashes` in order to properly account for any quotes that are in the string. Then `preg_quote` escapes the regular expression characters.

However, the problem is that quotes are escaped with backslash, e.g. `\'`. But then `preg_quote` escapes the backslash with another one, e.g. `\\'`. So this leaves the quote unescaped once again. Switching the two functions does not work either because that would leave an unescaped backslash which is then interpreted as a special regular expression character.

Is there a function in PHP to accomplish the task? Or how would one do it?

Comment: Where is your regex? Post that too

Comment: Oh, I thought the problem is independent of the actual regex I am using. At the moment I am trying to use `'\(?i)(?<=^|[^a-z])'.preg_quote(addslashes($string)).'\i'` which does not work.

Comment: Your delimiters are wrong, use slashes or tildes instead. `addslashes` is useless. Use `preg_quote` second parameter. Note that `(?<=^|[^a-z])` is the same than `(?<![a-z])`

Comment: Sorry, typo. Of course it is `'/(?i)(?<=^|[^a-z])'.preg_quote(addslashes($string)).'/i'`.

Comment: I get it from the value of an `<input>`.

Comment: Yes but what is value of `$string`?

Comment: You mean in a scenario that is problematic? It could be for example `Einstein's` or `Einstein"s`. It is surprising that so much hinges on the particular example. Does one need special escapes for different scenarios?

Comment: You just need `'/(?<![a-z])'.preg_quote($string, '/').'/i'`

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work. Still have to figure out what the second parameter `'/'` is doing.

Comment: @Daniel : take a look at the php manual. (or use an IDE like aptana that contains the description of all php functions)

Comment: It seems to escapes `/`'s in the string so it isn't count as regular expression character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way is to use [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) and specify the used [pattern delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

> preg_quote() takes str and puts a backslash in front of every character that is part of the regular expression syntax... characters are: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`

Trying to use a backslash as delimiter is a bad idea. Usually you pick a character, that's not used in the pattern. Commonly used is *slash* `/pattern/`, *tilde* `~pattern~`, *number sign* `#pattern#` or *percent sign* `%pattern%`. It is also possible to use bracket style delimiters: `(pattern)`

Your regex with modification mentioned in comments by @CasimiretHippolyte and @anubhava.

```
$pattern = '/(?<![a-z])' . preg_quote($string, "/") . '/i';
```

Maybe wanted to use `\b` [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). No need for any additional escaping.